# DotNetOpenAuth LinkedIn post share error using Asp.Net MVC

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, dotnetopenauth

**DotNetOpenAuth** is an amazing package. However, I keep hitting some hurdle or other. Till now most of them got solved, now I have hit a problem, which is taking up a lot of my time.

**The Problem**:
I want to share a post on linkedin using DotNetOpenAuth. I was able to share a few posts a while back, but all of a sudden things are now broken, and I am not able to post shares anymore. I do not recollect making much changes in my code. Can someone have a look at my diagnosis, code and see if I am messing something up?

**The Diagnosis**:
I ran fiddler while making requests via my code and via LinkedIn's [Rest Console](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest-console). Here's the Fiddler output for both scenarios:

Fiddler Output for request that was made via Rest Console provided by linkedin

```
POST /v1/people/~/shares HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="{consumer_key}",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1362258084",oauth_nonce="-141812272",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="{access_token}",oauth_signature="HBMUfvHYJAxz%2BszxStVJ%2BhfQPEQ%3D"
Host: api.linkedin.com
Content-Length: 645
X-Target-URI: http://api.linkedin.com
Content-Type: application/xml
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<share>
    <comment>test comment</comment>
    <content>
        <title>test title</title>
        <submitted-url>{my_test_url}</submitted-url>
        <submitted-image-url>{my_image_url}</submitted-image-url>
    </content>
    <visibility>
        <code>anyone</code>
    </visibility>
</share>
```

Fiddler output for request that was made via my code(using DNOA):

```
POST http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth oauth_token="{access_token}",oauth_consumer_key="{my_consumer_key}",oauth_nonce="ECYFLc0l",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="FobR745YkMlmBpOqoTDr8CwGZIQ%3D",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_timestamp="1362263560"
Content-Type: application/xml
Host: api.linkedin.com
Content-Length: 510
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <share>
    <comment>test comment</comment>
    <content>
      <title>test title</title>
      <description>test description</description>
      <submitted-url>{my_test_url}</submitted-url>
      <submitted-image-url>{my_image_url}</submitted-image-url>
    </content>
    <visibility>
      <code>anyone</code>
    </visibility>
  </share>
```

**More details:**

I know that I need to pass scope while performing oauth authentication, so already have this in place. I also get proper permission prompt that reads "NETWORK UPDATES Retrieve and post updates to LinkedIn as you" when user is authorizing my application

Do note that I do get an access token, and I am able to perform some read operations, like for getting user details using this token, however, I am not able to use the token to share posts on LinkedIn. Currently the implementation is using LinkedIn oAuth 1.0a.

Here's my code block as well:

```
public bool PostToLinkedIn(WebConsumer consumer, string sShareMessageXml, string accessToken = null)
{
    var payload = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sShareMessageXml);

    AuthorizedTokenResponse token = null;
    bool bIsAccessTokenSupplied = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken);
    if (!bIsAccessTokenSupplied)
    {
        token = consumer.ProcessUserAuthorization();
    }
    if (token != null || bIsAccessTokenSupplied)
    {
        this.AccessToken = bIsAccessTokenSupplied ? accessToken : token.AccessToken;

        var resourceEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares", HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest);
        HttpWebRequest request = consumer.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(resourceEndpoint, AccessToken);
        request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = payload.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(payload, 0, payload.Length);
        }

        var response = consumer.Channel.WebRequestHandler.GetResponse(request);

        var responseData = response.GetResponseReader().ReadToEnd();

        var xmlData = XDocument.Parse(responseData);

        if (xmlData.Elements(XName.Get("update")).Any())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please let me know if you need more details. Any help would be great.

I have posted a brief version of the same problem on DNOA's google group as well [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dotnetopenid/Kj7FyMHnVcI). Hopefully someone has faced this issue and has a solution.

Comment: Can you [turn on logging](http://tinyurl.com/dnoalogs) and include the signature base string in your question?

Comment: Also, if you're using .NET 4.0 or later, can you try the new way of sending OAuth 1.0 requests as described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/dotnetopenid/Delegating%E2%80%8BHandler/dotnetopenid/hMvPRtsewsI/loOn56kOjF4J)?

Comment: I know its late, but just realized I didn't reply to Andrew. Thanks Andrew for your responses. I turned on debuggin tried many stuff, but it was not working. So I ended up doing manual oAuth. Anyways, thanks for your time!